# I can not get my collision to work in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame, time, random

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

white = (255,255,255)
green = (0,255,0)
black = (0,0,0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

boy = pygame.image.load("pig.png")
fence = pygame.image.load("fence.png")

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = (display_width/2),(display_height/2)
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(2)
    game_loop()
def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()
def crash():
    message_display("Game Over")
def fence1(fencex, fencey, fencew, fenceh, color):
    gameDisplay.blit(fence, (fencex, fencey, fencew, fenceh))
def collision():
    pig_image = pygame.image.load("pig.png")
    pig_rect = pig_image.get_rect()
    fence_image = pygame.image.load("fence.png")
    fence_rect = fence_image.get_rect()
    if pig_rect.colliderect(fence_rect):
        crash()
def game_loop():
    fence_startx = 900
    fence_starty = gameDisplay.get_height() * 0.8
    fence_speed = 15
    fence_width = 50
    fence_height = 50

    x = gameDisplay.get_width() * 0.1
    y = gameDisplay.get_height() * 0.8
    y_change = 0
    on_ground = True
    gravity = .9

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    if on_ground:
                        y_change = -20
                        on_ground = False

        y_change += gravity
        y += y_change
        if y >= 500:
            y = 500
            y_change = 0
            on_ground = True

        gameDisplay.fill(green)
        gameDisplay.blit(boy, (x, y))
        fence1(fence_startx, fence_starty, fence_width, fence_height, white)
        fence_startx -= fence_speed
        randomx = random.randint(1,3)

        if fence_startx <= -50:
            if randomx == 1:
                fence_startx = 1000
            if randomx == 2:
                fence_startx = 800
            if randomx == 3:
                fence_startx = 1500

        collision()

        pygame.display.flip()

        clock.tick(60)

game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

For some reason when I run this code, it spams me "Game Over". Could someone please help me on this issue. I use a collision function in this code. Is using the pygame.rect code the best way to do collision in pygame? Everything works except for my collision in the game. I would greatly appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: To see what's happening, examine the rects you're testing for collision, for instance using `print`.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes, I have already done this and it just puts the results out rapidly every frame.

Comment: Look at your `collision()` function. From what I can tell, it looks like you are loading two images from two png files. When images are loaded, they default to a rect of the form `(x, y, image_width, image_height)` where `(x, y)` is `(0, 0)`. Therefore, it is unsurprising that your two rects are overlapping and colliding if they both have their top-left corners at `(0, 0)`!

Comment: @CodeSurgeon Thanks, but how would I add the x,y to the rects?

Comment: You could do something like `my_rect.rect.x = new_x_value`. I would look at the answer @skrx provided though, it should answer your questions more thoroughly!

Answer (score 2):

In the `collision` function you create two rects but leave their coordinates at the default position `(0, 0)` so the rects overlap. You should add rects for the player and the fence in the main `game_loop` function, set their `x` and `y` (or the `topleft`) attributes to the desired coordinates and then update them every iteration of the while loop. To check if the rects collide, pass them to the collision function and do this:

```
def collision(boy_rect, fence_rect):
    if boy_rect.colliderect(fence_rect):
        # I'm just printing it to shorten the code example.
        print('crash')
```

Here's a minimal, complete example:

```
import random
import pygame


pygame.init()

green = (0,255,0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

boy = pygame.Surface((40, 60))
boy.fill((0, 40, 100))
fence = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
fence.fill((100, 60, 30))


def collision(boy_rect, fence_rect):
    if boy_rect.colliderect(fence_rect):
        # I'm just printing it to shorten the code example.
        print('crash')


def game_loop():
    fence_speed = 15
    # Create a fence and a boy rect and set their x,y or topleft coordinates.
    fence_rect = fence.get_rect()
    fence_rect.x = 900
    fence_rect.y = gameDisplay.get_height() * 0.8

    x = gameDisplay.get_width() * 0.1
    y = gameDisplay.get_height() * 0.8
    boy_rect = boy.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))

    y_change = 0
    on_ground = True
    gravity = .9

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    if on_ground:
                        y_change = -20
                        on_ground = False

        y_change += gravity
        y += y_change
        if y >= 500:
            y = 500
            y_change = 0
            on_ground = True
        boy_rect.y = y  # Update the rect position.

        gameDisplay.fill(green)
        gameDisplay.blit(boy, boy_rect)
        gameDisplay.blit(fence, fence_rect)
        # Update the position of the fence rect.
        fence_rect.x -= fence_speed

        if fence_rect.x <= -50:
            # You can use random.choice to pick one of these values.
            fence_rect.x = random.choice((800, 1000, 1500))
        # Pass the two rects and check if they collide.
        collision(boy_rect, fence_rect)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

game_loop()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I got this error when trying to blit the rects to the screen. TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not pygame.Rect

Comment: You can't blit `pygame.Rect`s, only `pygame.Surface`s. The rects are just used to store the position/coordinates and the size of your objects. For example, to blit the `fence` surface/image at the `fence_rect` coordinates just write: `gameDisplay.blit(fence, fence_rect)`.

Comment: I did this and the errors are gone, but it still does not work.

Comment: Either post a new question if this bug is unrelated or add your updated code to this question.